# NAN values in tf.keras.looses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy function

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am presently using a pretrained VGG16 model for the classification of imagenet Large Scale Vision Recognition Challenge (i.e. the downsampled resized 32 by 32 image version). I have set the top of the model to be false for the classification of this image set into 1000 categories. I am using the Adam optimisation technique and sparse_categorical_crossentropy for the loss function. However, after fitting the compiled model to my training sets and for validation, I am getting loss: nan values. I have tried different methods I know, but the result still remain the same. Suggestions on what to do will greatly be appreciated. A part of the output of the result is as shown below:
Epoch 1/100
282/20018 [..............................] - ETA: 15:06 - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0012

The code for the compiled based model is also as shown below:

```
base_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

while for the fitting of the model is also as shown below:

```
from datetime import datetime
BATCH_SIZE = 64
channels=3

callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./log/{}'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")))]   
train_batch = training.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE) 
valid_batch = validation.repeat().batch(BATCH_SIZE)
history = base_model.fit(train_batch,
                    epochs=100, #batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    steps_per_epoch = 1281167//BATCH_SIZE,
                    validation_steps=10,
                    validation_data=valid_batch,  callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with the following info?
What does your data look like (label shape, example value)
What happens to loss after several epochs, is it still NaN?
What does your model output layer look like (activation function - I'm guessing since vgg its sigmoidal?)?

Comment: The data are images from imagenet_resized/32x32 for the Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge (ILSVRC), which have training set of 1281167 images and validation of 50,000. Image data (intensity values) are between 0-255 and converted to float values in the range 0 to 1. image.shape (32, 32, 3) and with batch size of 64. Also, below are a few sample labels from the 1000 output categories:
n02119789
n02100735
n02110185
n02096294
n02102040
n02066245
n02509815
n02124075
. The output layer activation function is sigmoidal. Also after several epochs, the loss is still NAN.

Comment: could you explain how n02102040 is a valid label provided only 1000 classes?

Comment: The sample n02102040 is actually an example of the  word_id (synset) used by imagenet for grouping the images using synonym sets into different categories. The wordids are then mapped into the actual categories (i.e integer nymbers). For example, the mapping of this wordid: n02102040 to the actual category is as shown: n02102040 5 English_springerh_setter, where the first column is wordid (i.e. n02102040), the second column is the actual category number (i.e. 5) and the third column is the actual category name (i.e.English_springerh_setter). Similar mapping is done for all 1000 categories..